# Storing a base64 converted file in a variable for later use

Tags: javascript, json, file, variables, base64

**Situation:**

A form where the user can choose to attach a file, with a simple file selector, which converts the file  to Base64 right after it gets chosen and stores it for later use.

```
var handleFileSelect = function(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    var file = files[0];
    if (files && file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(readerEvt) {
            var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
            konvertierteDatei = btoa(binaryString);
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
};

if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    document.getElementById('attachementName').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
} else {
    alert('Die Datei APIs werden von diesem Browser nicht vollständig unterstützt.');
}
```

**Problem**

It worked before with a bad kind of workaround where I stored the base64 encoded file in a hidden textarea and then later had it added to my JSON data by getting the value of said textarea.

I wanted to make this "better" by storing the encoded file in `konvertierteDatei` and later have the value of that added to the data, but it doesn't work no matter how I put it.

**Solution:**

Edit: Here is a working snippet, it seems like @H.B. is right and I tried to access `konvertierteDatei` from a different scope

```js
var handleFileSelect = function(evt) {
var files = evt.target.files;
var file = files[0];
if (files && file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(readerEvt) {
        var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
        konvertierteDatei = btoa(binaryString);
        document.getElementById("base64textarea").value = btoa(binaryString);
    };

    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
};

if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
document.getElementById('attachementName').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
} else {
alert('Die Datei APIs werden von diesem Browser nicht vollständig unterstützt.');
}
```

```html
<input class="infrastruktur__input infrastruktur__input---file" id="attachementName" type="file"/>
<br>
<h1>Base64 encoded file</h1>
     <textarea id="base64textarea" placeholder="Base64 will appear here" cols="50" rows="15"></textarea>
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? The variable is `undefined`? It throws an error? How are you adding the value to the data?

Comment: Have you tried storing it in the browser memories?

Comment: no error message, the variable doesn't change. It doesn't get affected at all by the function. How I add the value doesn't matter, as tested with the console `konvertierteDatei` stays empty the whole time

Comment: `konvertierteDatei` is not assigned until `reader.onload` is triggered. are you sure this happens? (what happens if the reader ancounters an error?) also, are you sure `btoa(binaryString)` works as intended?

Comment: ah, so what does `btoa` do? could you post the code?

Comment: @TimothyGroote: [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) is a native JS function for encoding to base-64.

Comment: I've played around with it some more and it seems like neither `reader.onload` nor even  `handleFileSelect` get triggered, so the fault must be somewhere in `if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    document.getElementById('attachementName').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
} else {
    alert('Die Datei APIs werden von diesem Browser nicht vollständig unterstützt.');
}`

Comment: i can't tell if there is anything wrong with that code other than the fact that it seems syntactically correct. i'd need to see the accompanying HTML to tell if you are trying to fetch the element in the correct way. (also, to help us help you, it would be nice if you could post all the code to make a minimal, working example that allows us to reproduce your problem)

Comment: Your code works as intended for me. When i log the value of `konvertierteDatei` after its assignment, it logs the base64 value. Maybe you try to access the value in the wrong scope or at the wrong time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your code seems like it should function, but i think you're trying to add the event listener before the element exists in the DOM or something.

Adding an event listener to wait for the DOM to finish loading all elements was enough for me to get it to work ;

```js
var handleFileSelect = function(evt) {
    alert("file selected");
    var files = evt.target.files;
    var file = files[0];
    if (files && file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(readerEvt) {
            var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
            konvertierteDatei = btoa(binaryString);
            console.log(konvertierteDatei);
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
};



document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
       document.getElementById('attachementName').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    } else {
        alert('Die Datei APIs werden von diesem Browser nicht vollständig unterstützt.');
    }
});
```

```html
<input class="formOne__input formOne__input---file" id="attachementName" type="file"/>
```

Comment: I'll accept this as answer because this was the solution for some problems IE caused. The original problem however was due to me trying to access variables outside of their scope. Thank you!